# openapi documentation how to handle extension in the path

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

I have URLs like:

```
/return/{pid}.xml?d1='123'&d2='345'
/return/{pid}.json?d1='123'&d2='345'
```

the swagger specification calls for:
path:/return/{pid}
....

but how can I map the extension ie

path:`/return/{pid}.xml`

or

path:`/return/{pid}.json`

It is a jersey+spring mvc application - so both the URLs are hitting the same controller and only based on the extension the rest framework is going to generate the xml / json output.

I can't ignore the extension from the path ie:
path:`/return/{pid}`

because the user needs to know that he/she has to provide the file extension as part of the URL. Also I can't use two paths corresponding to xml / json because they are treated the same by the application. In addition it will duplicate things (I am not sure whether there is a fall-through like mechanism just like "case" statements in c++/java "switch" block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swagger specs,You can define the file extensions  in the path as below :

```
/return/{pId}.{fileExtension}
```

and define the fileExtension in parameters .

also the below is valid (not for your case) :

```
/return/pid.{fileExtension}
```